# kubuntu 12.10 - problem with netbeans 7.3 and java

Tags: 12.10, software-installation, kubuntu, java, netbeans

I have kubuntu 12.10 and I have installed netbeans from official site (https://netbeans.org/downloads/). Before I had already installed java from java ppa repository ppa:webupd8team/java (https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/java). In particular I have manually installed `java-8-installer` from repository manager.

The problem is that after installation netbeans works fine, but after computer reboot if I open it, just the netbeans splash screen is shown and the it closes.

Here is the output from terminal of `usr/local/netbeans-7.3/bin/netbeans`:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=32m; support was removed in 8.0
```

How to solve it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install packages java-7-installer and java-7-set-default.

You can remove java-8-installer, as Java 8 is not yet officialy released.

Answer (score 0):

Too late to answer but may this useful for user that encounter the same issue.

Netbeans 7.3 not working with Java 8, there is new NetBeans 8.0 release or later in official site will work with Java 8.